# Database and API calls are not working in iOS background using Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, hybrid-mobile-app

Need help on how to effectively extend the background time of the ios app and do the DB and API calls in entire session. Right now when the app is in background mode it automatically crashes or logs out that's why we are not able to save the data in the whole session.

Scenario: I book a session from 11:00 AM To 12:00 PM. In this, I have several sessions like:
Session 1: 11:00 AM to 11:15 AM,
Session 2: 11:15 AM to 11:30 AM,
Session 3: 11:30 AM to 11:45 AM,
Session 4: 11:45 AM to 12:00 AM

There are 3 states to the user: 1. Checked in (Yellow Color), 2. Completed (Green Color), 3. Absent (Red Color)
So we have to save all the states of all the sessions when the time is same as mobile time.

Comment: If you need an iOS app to run constantly, the user has to keep it in the foreground. Otherwise you have about 5 seconds from when DidEnterBackground is called to start a background task (BeginBackgroundTask), after that you can start your cleanup, db shutdown, etc.. and end the background task, make sure you do it before BackgroundTimeRemaining hits 0 otherwise the app process is killed.

Comment: Xamarin has a complete iOS backgrounding overview available : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/